# How do I target .NET 4.0.3 on XP using Visual Studio 2012? Application fails to run with "not a valid Win32 application"

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, windows-7, windows-xp, visual-studio-2012

I have a large application targeting .NET 4.0.3 that needs to run on XP. It builds fine using Visual Studio 2010 SP1 and runs properly on XP.

Building using Visual Studio 2012 targeting .NET 4.0.3 also builds fine and runs fine on Windows 7 but it fails to run on XP. I get an error saying MyApp.exe is not a valid Win32 application.

How do I continue to target .NET 4.0.3 with support for XP machines using Visual Studio 2012?

Comment: Visual Studio 2012 does not support Windows XP as a target without some workarounds (see http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/11/en-us/products/compatibility ).

Comment: I can build a .NET 4.0 application using Visual Studio 2012 and it runs fine on XP. It just seems to have a problem with .NET 4.0.3.

Comment: Does it work on the XP machine after installing http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=29053 ?

Comment: The XP machine already has the .NET 4.0.3 update installed. It runs fine on XP when built with Visual Studio 2010 but fails with VS2012.

Comment: @John Saunders Google is a thing, but here you go anyway http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2012/03/05/update-4-0-3-for-the-microsoft-net-framework-4.aspx

Comment: 4.0.3 is an update for Microsoft .NET Framework 4. Supported on XP. See here http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29053

Comment: @MalcolmO'Hare: I would never have googled for it since I didn't previously know that there _were_ platform updates. Thanks.

Comment: I've also experienced the same issue. Deploying an app via ClickOnce in VS2012 causes Windows XP users to receive `not a valid Win32 appliaction` errors, but Windows Vista and Windows 7 users are unaffected. I posted about it here: http://markdownpad.com/news/2012/version-1.3.5.6/

Comment: This problem is a subject of the blog post *[Setup.exe is not a valid Win32 application](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsnetsetup/archive/2012/10/16/setup-exe-is-not-a-valid-win32-application.aspx)*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not certain this will work, but try the trick [shown here](https://web.archive.org/web/20130314124514/http://supportxp.com/2012/03/30/editbins-dirty-little-secret/) to manually set the subsystem version with `EditBin.exe`.

Comment: In a VS2012 environment, use `editbin.exe "$(TargetPath)" /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS,5.01 /OSVERSION:5.1`

Answer (score 9):

We are also having this problem. It isn't a matter of what framework your application is targeting (we are targetting the 4.0 client).

The problem is that Visual Studio 2012 will not produce a click once setup.exe that will run on XP. The error is missleading as it always reports that the program is not a valid Win32 application. It does this on any version of XP including 64-bit versions.

It is not your application causing the problem, it is the setup.exe produced by VS2012. The only way we have found to get around it is to publish using VS2010.

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft just recently posted a fix for this. (Express versions included.)

Details at: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/smondal/archive/2012/10/15/setup-exe-is-not-a-valid-win32-application.aspx

Comment: It's only solved for native applications. 4.0.3 is not working yet (but 4.0 is)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to set the target system requirements under the Project Properties -> Publish -> Prerequisites panel (VS2012 with Update 1). Even though you're building for .NET 4 (Project Properties -> Application -> Target Framework) you'll need to change the prerequisites from 4.5 to 4 as it wont drop the requirements automatically.

Building with a target of 4 but prereq of 4.5 will start the installer but fail on system checks

Answer (score 0):

VS2012 Update 1 is supposed to resolve this issue. However, I am not sure what options to use though, is it Toolset under Project Properties->General->Platform Toolset?

Comment: Note that this is not project properties, but solution properties.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me - just build your solution in Studio 2012, and take a copy of the contents of the solution from the Debug folder.  Make sure XP client has .net 4 installed.

Answer (score 0):

Add to your `.csproj` file

```xml
  <!-- v4.0.3 target framework is >4.0, so default is 6.00 (Vista), set it back to 5.01 (XP) -->
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(TargetFrameworkIdentifier)' == '.NETFramework'">
    <SubsystemVersion>5.01</SubsystemVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
```