# Winforms: Not a Valid Win32 Application

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2012, publish, bootstrapper

I've created a simple Windows Form Application using VS2012 and I'm trying to install it to an XP machine.

Unfortunately I get the following error message:

> setup.exe is not a valid Win32 application.

Admittedly, I did use the .net 4.5 framework which is an issue on XP machines. But I have now created a test application using .net 2.0 and get the same problem.

I'm developing the app on a win7 x64 machine and tried setting the platform to x86 in the configuration manager with out any joy.

Is this me or VS 2012? I've managed to install a test app using VS2010?

I had a similar issue when I tried to work on a Lightswitch application using VS2012 and abandoned it.

Any suggestions?

Cheers,
Numb

Comment: Support for targeting XP with VS2012 is planned but not ready.

Comment: This is also a problem for Windows Server 2003, with the same workarounds.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I target .NET 4.0.3 on XP using Visual Studio 2012? Application fails to run with "not a valid Win32 application"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319952/how-do-i-target-net-4-0-3-on-xp-using-visual-studio-2012-application-fails-to)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is a blog on the subject and a workaround:

[Setup.exe is not a valid Win32 application](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vsnetsetup/archive/2012/10/16/setup-exe-is-not-a-valid-win32-application.aspx)

> Clickonce bootstrapper engine (setup.exe) that was shipped with Visual
>   Studio 2012 is NOT compatible with any OS below Windows Vista.  So,
>   the above error message is expected and by design. The reason for this
>   behavior is because the bootstrapper is compiled using the VC compiler
>   and the Dev11 VC compiler does not support Windows XP.

Comment: Thank you. Confirmed my worst fears!!

Comment: hm, I looked at that and I can't see that "General" tab on my Property Pages, so I can change it to XP. Any idea why I only get the "Configuration" tab? Thank you

Comment: These property pages are only for VC++ projects (with the mentioned patch applied)

Comment: Thousand people complaining: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3041773-bring-back-the-basic-setup-and-deployment-project-